# Pass application event to another component in Lightning Flow?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow

I'm trying to build a form of "journey" through lightning components in the new Flow designer but I'm having a hard time making the flow play. Basically, I've got `component 1` that let's the user select an account - selecting an account triggers an application event and another component listens for that event to render Assets that belongs to the account in `component 2`. This works fine If I just put the different components on a Lightning Page. However, I wish to embed each component in a `Flow`, and have each component on a separate screen. E.g screen #1 shows `component 1`, -> user selects an account and clicks `Next` and `component 2` on screen #2 displays the assets that belongs to `component 1` on screen #1.

I did include the recordId in a design attribute and I can see the recordId being clicked when I go to screen #2, but for some reason, `component 2` does not receive the event since it sits on a different screen.

Here's the event for `component 1`

```
onRowAction: function( component, event, helper ) {
        var action = event.getParam( 'action' );
        var row = event.getParam( 'row' );
        if (action.name == 'check_record') {
            component.set("v.recordId", row.Id)
            var event = $A.get("e.c:AccountSelected")
            event.setParams({
                accoId: row.Id
            });
        }
        event.fire();
    }
```

And then the handler that listens to the event in `component 2`:

```
<aura:handler event="c:AccountSelected" action="{!c.queryAssets}" />

queryAssets: function(component, event, helper) {
        let accountId = event.getParam('accoId');
            helper.callServer(component, "c.getResources", function(response) {
                component.set("v.assetList", response);
            }, {accId: accountId});
        },
```

Why is `component 2` not receiving anything when the event is fired in `component 1`

Answer (score 0):

Events won't work in your use case because when you fire the event, cmp 2 doesn't even exist. It would work if both components were dropped on the same screen.  Refer here: https://developingflow.com/2018/06/11/lightning-components-in-flow/

You need to use design attributes on both the components and use flow as your data carrier.

CMP1:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global" >
   <aura:attribute name="accId" type="String" required="true" />
   <!-- HERE GOES YOUR UI CODE -->
</aura:component>
```

CMP1 Design File:

```
<design:component>
   <design:attribute name="accId" label="Account Id" />
</design:component>
```

CMP1 JS Controller:

```
onRowAction: function( component, event, helper ) {
    var action = event.getParam( 'action' );
    var row = event.getParam( 'row' );
    if (action.name == 'check_record') {
        component.set("v.accId", row.Id);
    }
}
```

CMP2:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global" >
   <aura:attribute name="accId" type="String" required="true" />
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{! this}" action="{! c.doInit}"/>
   <!-- HERE GOES YOUR UI CODE FOR CMP 2-->
</aura:component>
```

CMP2 Design File:

```
<design:component>
   <design:attribute name="accId" label="Account Id" />
</design:component>
```

CMP2 JS Controller:

```
    doInit: function( component, event, helper ) {
    let accountId = component.get("v.accId");
            helper.callServer(component, "c.getResources", function(response) {
                component.set("v.assetList", response);
            }, {accId: accountId});
        },
}
```

Your code for both components should look like this. You just need to make sure that you are getting accId from cmp1 and passing it to cmp2. This you can do while dropping your lightning component on flow screen. All design attributes comes under Input/Output section in flow screen. So under output section on screen 1, store accId value in some flow variable and use same variable to pass accId as an input to cmp2.

Comment: I'm using
`<design:component>
    <design:attribute name="recordId" label="Record Id" />
</design:component>`
on both my components  (component 1 and component 2) and then I'm storing that in a variable on the flow - not entirely sure what else I need to do to make it work..

Comment: Did you check what value you are getting in flow after cmp1 and before cmp2. do not fire any event from cmp1 because it wont be captured by any other cmp. Instead, use component.set to set value in your attribute. when value of component attribute is changed, it automatically reflects in flow as well. once set properly, you should be able to pass the same to cmp2 which lies on the next screen of your flow. you also need to put your cmp2 logic in init because your queryAssets won't be called. So move your logic to init.

Comment: Also, it is recommended that do not define recordId as your attribute because it is a standard attribute which get inherited to component if force:hasRecordId is used in component implementation.

Comment: Not sure I follow, can you clarify? 
> you check what value you are getting in flow after cmp1 and before cmp2

Also, what other options do I have than to fire an event? How else would I specify the record Id for another component to use

Comment: I have updated the answer with code. How your components should look like. Are you showing next button of flow to move to next screen. If yes, then code in answer should work, otherwise I'll update the code with logic to move flow to next screen automatically.

Comment: Do I need to pass in the design attribute through a variable in the flow itself?

Comment: yes. you have to pass flow variable from flow to cmp2